# Access elements by Custom Attribute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, custom-attributes

I am wondering if I am able to access `Html` elements in `aspx` from code behind by custom attribute name. Like

```
HtmlElement[] allElements = Page.FindElementByCustomName("custom-name");
```

and it will give me an array of all elements with that attribute suppose my aspx is as below

```
<a runat="server" custom-name = "any">Faf</a>
<a runat="server">AB</a>
<a runat="server" custom-name = "any">Amla</a>
```

and `allElements` will have two `a` elements i.e

```
<a runat="server" custom-name = "any">Faf</a>
<a runat="server" custom-name = "any">Amla</a>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Down voting is not a bad thing but down vote without comment sounds like you got beaten by your wife and taking out frustration on me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through all controls in a page, but it will have to be done recursively. For example, start with Page.Controls, then, for each control, iterate through its Controls collection. For a control to take attributes it needs to implement IAttributeAccessor; you can check if the control in your iteration implements this interface. It is an interface that is required when you are to insert custom attributes on markup. For example, WebControl implements it. If now, when you try to add a custom attribute, ASP.NET will fail saying that there is no property with that name.
Something like:

```
public static void ListControls(ControlCollection controls, List<Control> controlsFound)
{
    foreach (var control in controls.OfType<Control>())
    {
        if (control is IAttributeAccessor)
        {
            controlsFound.Add(control);
            ListControls(control.Controls, controlsFound);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you should call from your page:

```
var controlsFound = new List<Control>();
ListControls(this.Controls, controlsFound);
```

In the end, just iterate through controlsFound, which you know is a collection of IAttributeAccessor and retrieve attribute attribute-name:

```
var attr = (control as IAttributeAccessor).GetAttribute("attribute-name");
```

Comment: Are foundControls and controlsFound same?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Corrected it, thanks. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: What are they, please? Try now.

Comment: You are awesome :) working fine. Though I don't know about IAttributeAccessor but I will learn that. Thank Richardo

Comment: You're welcome! It is an interface that is required when you are to insert custom attributes on markup. For example, WebControl implements it. If now, when you try to add a custom attribute, ASP.NET will fail saying that there is no property with that name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just did!